# How to update the due date only field in a task flow to 90 days from now

Tags: visual-workflow

I need to create a flow that triggers a task to be created when an opportunity is closed won. I need the due date of the task to be 90 days from now, but don't know how to make this happen with the due date only field. It only allows for a date to go into that field. I even tried to add a separate step to update the date field but wasn't sure which steps would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce allows you to add days to a date (in formulas, which you should be able to use to set date fields as part of an update action in a flow) using simple addition. E.g. `MyDateField__c + 60` would add 60 days.